# IE CSS Issue with nest LI tags

Tags: css, internet-explorer

The footer in the folowing site contains a sitemap:

http://www.openawards.org.uk/

It doesn't look right in IE and I can't figure it out can anyone

Answer (score 2):

Remove `float:left` from `#explore ul li a`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your float left for the a tags. Try looking at the before pseudo selector such as ...

```
#explore ul li a:before {
 clear: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like IE is having a problem with the `width` of your `li`s, so it is not clearing the shorter links.

Set a `width` to the `li`s and it should work.